# How in java to replace 220 lines of code per one line?

Tags: java

In my app I have several groups of variables attributes with their own code. For instance, there are 220 variables, which convert text to numbers:

```
P1 = Integer.parseInt(S1);
P2 = Integer.parseInt(S2);
...
P220 = Integer.parseInt(S220);
```

Is it possible to write this code with one or two strings, not with 220? Like this:

`Pn = Integer.parseInt(Sn)`, where n - number in the range 1 and 220.

Comment: Consider using an array.

Comment: Arrays or List, like `p[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[ i ])`, in a `for` loop from `0` to`219`. This will do

Answer (score 6):

The obvious way would be to use arrays :

```
int[] S = new String[220];
int[] P = new int[220];
for (int i = 0; i < P.length; i++)
    P[i] = Integer.parseInt(S[i]);
```

It would also simplify the code in which you populate those Strings.